# Is it possible to call child static method from parent type?

Tags: java

I have 3 child class `Child_1, Child_2, Child_3` and each has unique imagePath.

Therefore, i implement `public static String getImage()` since all instance share the same image.

Here is the problem. I want to call child static method from Parent instance `p`.

```java
private Image showImage(Parent p){
    Image image = null;
    try {           
        image = new Image(new FileInputStream(m.getImage()); // <- static method call
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Of course, i could use `instanceof` and invoke static method based on class.

```java
if(m instanceof Child_1) Child_1.getImage();
else if (m instance of Child_2) Child_2.getImage();
else Child_3.getImage();
```

Let say if i have 10 child class, it is not easy to use if else statement and call it one by one.

Is there any way to invoke child static method from parent instance in Java ??

Comment: Wrong approach. You want to not use static here. Instead you should research how to properly create abstract classes and how to use them in terms of polymorphism.

Comment: Template pattern is what you are looking for. Parent could be abstract and define an abstract getImage() method. Each chield will have to implement this method and parent can only refrence its own abstract getImage() method. As @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica hs mentioned mentioned.

Comment: So abstract getImage() is instance method?? Could we have static abstract method ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want that method to be static in the first place? You need to create a parent class maybe abstract and then use runtime polymorphism anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach to the problem. You should be relying on [Polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) for this type of problem.

One solution might be to declare an interface `ImageProcessor`:

```
public interface ImageProcessor {
  Image showImage(Parent p)
}
```

The all your `Child_2`, `Child_2`... classes should implement `ImageProcessor` and write their implementations.

Now you do not need to use if-else statements to run specific behavior. You can just call:

```
m.showImage(parent)
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers if you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

As all the others mentioned before, the usual way in Java is to use polymorphism.
This means that you declare an abstract class with the abstract method getImage() which can be implemented by the child class itself.

So your example would change to something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionExample {

    private Image showImage(Parent p){
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream(this.getImage());
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    protected abstract String getImage();
}

public class ChildClass extends AbstractFunctionExample {

    private final String path;

    public ChildClass(String pathToImage) {
        this.path = pathToImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getImage() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason you can not use this approach?